# Dualboot | After synced time on windows linux time is wrong

Tags: manjaro, time, timezone, clock

After i synced the windows time my hardware clock time is bad.

```
timedatectl 
               Local time: Sun 2023-10-01 15:38:05 CEST
           Universal time: Sun 2023-10-01 13:38:05 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2023-10-01 13:38:05
                Time zone: Europe/Budapest (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

```
sudo hwclock 
2023-10-01 15:38:47.644031+02:00
```

The **UTC** and the **RTC** time are right, timezone is right,  but the **CEST** time is **wrong**. What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

> The UTC and the RTC time are right, timezone is right, but the CEST time is wrong.

**No!*** The UTC time and the RTC times are **wrong**. I mean, it's not 13:38 now in UTC, at all, it's 11:38.

So, that's the thing: your Linux thinks your RTC is set to UTC time (which, honestly, is the sanest thing to do) but it's set to your local time.

> ```
>      RTC in local TZ: no
> ```

should be yes, *if you actually plan to keep your RTC in a local time zone* (I'd advise against that, because suddenly your RTC needs to be adjusted twice a year for daylight savings time, and if you travel with a laptop, what even *is* local  time zone? How should the RTC know where you currently are? Why should it *care*?)

Windows *does* support using UTC as RTC time, so that's what I would do. However, [Windows' own NTP time synchronization will overwrite the RTC with the wrong (local) time](https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time) (instead of keeping it in UTC), so you'd need to disable the time sync under windows.

If you can't do that, your other option is to let your Linux system know that the RTC is in your local time zone, not in UTC, by running `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`. Again, the downside is that inherently, your RTC, whose job would really be to just keep track of "absolute" time, will have to make jumps when there's daylights saving time starting or ending, or when you walk into a different time zone.

Anecdote time: Assuming "Europe/Budapest" means you're in Hungary: I've been on vacation in Hungary nearly two decades ago, when I nearly walked into a different time zone, just to get pointed out that maybe I should stay away from *that* border without proper papers. It happens to the best of us; I do go to conferences that are typically in different time zones annually, typically (epidemics might have influenced that frequency lately).

Comment: "However, Windows' own NTP time synchronization will overwrite the RTC with the wrong (local) time (instead of keeping it in UTC), so you'd need to disable the time sync under windows." Do you have a link to any details about that bug?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time  first I could find.